# How to access data requested by Post method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to access data from a certain API using **POST** method but it returns back the actual list of params that I sent. Here is my code I don't know whether am doing this right, I will be glad for your help.

***This is my controller***

```
  #Request access token from ExactApi
  params =  {
             "code" => "#{code}",
             "redirect_uri" => '/auth/exact/callback',
             "grant_type"   => "authorization_code",
             "client_id"   => "{CLIENT_ID}",
             "client_secret" => "CLIENT_SECRET"
           }
uri = URI.parse('https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token')

#Encode the url into /x-www-form-urlencoded
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

#Transform http protocol into a secure protocol[https]
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # You should use VERIFY_PEER in production

#Send the request to the ExactApi and return the received data
res  = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
res.set_form_data(params)
puts "Received:: "+ res.body.to_yaml
```

***Output***

```
code[CODE]&redirect_uri=%2Fauth%2Fexact%2Fcallback&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_ID
```

How can I access the actual data returned from API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse('https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # You should use VERIFY_PEER in production
request.set_form_data({
     "code" => "#{code}",
     "redirect_uri" => '/auth/exact/callback',
     "grant_type"   => "authorization_code",
     "client_id"   => CLIENT_ID,
     "client_secret" => CLIENT_SECRET
})

response = http.request(request)
```

http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

However I would use [Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) instead of reinventing the Oauth wheel. Its pretty hard to get right. If you cannot find a ready made provider then creating a custom provider is pretty simple:

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class ExactOnline < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      # change the class name and the :name option to match your application name
      option :name, :exactonile

      option :client_options, {
        :site => "https://start.exactonline.nl",
        :authorize_url => "/api/oauth2/token"
      }

      uid { raw_info["id"] }

      info do
        {
          :email => raw_info["email"]
          # and anything else you want to return to your API consumers
        }
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/v1/me.json').parsed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I already have this `gem` [ExactOnline]( https://github.com/amirap/E-X-A-C-T-Online) that I was using to authenticate the user `ExactOnlineAPI`  How can i use it to send post request to exactOnline. This is what I have in omniauth.rb `provider :exact, '{CLIENT_ID}', 'SECRET CODE'`

Comment: Um, I don't think you should be using that Gem. It says so in the first line of the readme.

Comment: You should really learn Rails first before trying to do authentication with oauth - its way out of your league at the moment. And a step by step tutorial is out of scope for stackoverflow. There is [a railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) which is pretty dated but goes through the basics.

Comment: Alright Thanks, But just to be clear on this where are you   getting `http` variable `response = http.request(request) because am encountering  this error `undefined local variable or method `http' for` 
`

Comment: Woops, I really screwed up copy pasting the example together. Edited

Comment: hey @max, if I can access this data `env['omniauth.auth']["info], How do i access this method `raw_info()` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `puts` which outputs to the server console.  I'm confused where the output is.  You should set yourself up a view with the same name as the controller action your block of code is within, for example if this is the index action:

```
def index
  params= { your_hash_keys: "value" }
end
```

Then you should have an index.html.erb inside the app/views/controller_name/  In your controller instead of `puts "Received:: "+ res.body.to_yaml` use `@debug = "Received:: "+ res.body.to_yaml` and inside your view do something to output it like <%= @debug.inspect %>

Alternatively, and not recommended is to render inline in the controller:

```
render inline: "Received:: " + res.body.to_yaml
```

[Layouts and Rendering with inline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render-with-inline)

You also should rename your params variable, since that is used by Rails for the incoming parameters.  All in all I think a tutorial on MVC would be a good place to start.

Comment: He is still not actually sending the request - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: @max, Could you please provide me some examples which illustrate how to send and receive data using `POST method` because that's what am trying to archive